# How to stop overflow from interfering z-index?

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index, frontend

I have a 'ul' with dynamic data. Each list inside has an user image, and when you hover on the image, an info box will show up on the left side of the 'ul'.

When I set the 'ul' to be overflow-y:scroll, the part of the info box that's outside of the 'ul' will be cut.

Here's what it should look like. The blue area is the info box.
[image]

Here's what it looks like now: The blue area is cut.
[image]

Here's the css code:

```
.popUpRSVPList{
    padding-left:0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
}
.hoverToShowInfo{
    position: relative;
}
 .hoverToShowInfo .infoinfo {
  display: none;
}
.hoverToShowInfo:hover .infoinfo {
   position:absolute;
    left:-280px;
     top: -60px;
    display:block;   
     z-index: 10;
     top: 100%;
 }
```

Here is the html code:

```
<ul class="popUpRSVPList" >
  <li style="padding-left:20px;">
  <a class="hoverToShowInfo" href="">
      <!--Left Info Box, will show on hover-->
       <div class="col-sm-12 infoinfo" >
  </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:**
**The reason I set overflow-y:scroll; is that I need the ul to be scrollable and thus when there are hundreds of data, the 'ul' list will be shorter than the screen, and user can just scroll inside it to view each list.**

Here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/7gr7jvvh/
Please uncomment overflow-y:scroll. You will see the difference.

Comment: Create a CodePen or jsFiddle or something. It hard to tell what you want.

Comment: now your code shows nothing ? please share your full code

Comment: @sheriffderek After I set the overflow:hidden, overflow-y:scroll, the info box will be cut by the edge of the ul table. You can see it from the updated pictures.

Comment: @Naila The rest of the code is just for UI color and data. This should be all.

Comment: i think you can fix this with `overflow:visible` , but we can suggest anything without your relevant code

Comment: @Naila Thanks for your suggestion, please see the update. It also doesn't work when I set overflow:visible. Also, I have wrote all the css relevant code. Are you having issues seeing them from your end?

Comment: @WoShiNiBaBa Can you create a dummy snippet here

Comment: @Naila Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/7gr7jvvh/

Comment: @sheriffderek Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/7gr7jvvh/

Comment: I think there is no solution. There isn't a way to use the markup in the list, in some other place, even though you've hacked it together with positioning... it's in general - probably just not the right way to do this. You'll more likely need to use data attributes or on the fly javascript templates to achieve this in a way that is robust. The overflow isn't going to be able to 'be' and 'not be' at the same time.

Comment: @sheriffderek Yes I think you are right...

Comment: @sheriffderek If you change the position in '.hoverToShowInfo:hover .infoinfo' to fixed, it will show up, although it's assigned to a fixed position.

Comment: @WoShiNiBaBa - You can get something working... but when you start getting into various responsive layouts etc, I'm betting you'll wish that you had some components for each part that are connected with some data-flow.

Comment: @sheriffderek That's true. Can you be more specific? Should I use javascript to generate the info box for each data in the list?

Comment: @WoShiNiBaBa It really depends on too many things for me to help. The framework you may or may not use, the layouts etc. It's not something that can be answered here. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at given jsfiddle code hope you want this thing:

```css
.popUpRSVPList li { background: white;  list-style-type:none; padding:12px 15px; color: black;}
.popUpRSVPList li:nth-child(odd) { background: rgba(241,242,242,1); }
.popUpRSVPList{
    padding-left:0px;
     
/*    overflow-y: scroll;*/
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
     
}

.hoverToShowInfo{
    position: relative;
}
 .hoverToShowInfo .infoinfo {
  display: none;
}

.infoinfo div{
    width:270px;
}
 .hoverToShowInfo:hover .infoinfo {
   position:absolute;
    left:0px;
     top: -60px;
    display:block;   
     z-index: 10;
     top: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }
        span.rightNames {
    color: white;
}
.infoBoxFirstLine{
    background:rgba(49,66,84,1); 
    min-height:auto;
    max-width:270px;
    padding:12px 15px;
    
}
```

```html
<ul class="popUpRSVPList" >
 <li style="padding-left:20px;">
  <a class="hoverToShowInfo" href="">
  &User Name
<!--Left Info Box, will show on hover-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 infoinfo" >
      <div class="infoBoxFirstLine row " >
      
      <!--attendee profile image w-->
           <div class="leftImage" >
              <img src="" style="border-radius:150px; width:50px; height:50px;"/>
             <!--attendee name w-->
             <span class="rightNames"  style="">
                NAME 1
              </span>
          </div>
      <!--end-->
      
     </div>
      <div class="infoBoxFirstLine row " >
      
      <!--attendee profile image w-->
           <div class="leftImage" >
              <img src="" style="border-radius:150px; width:50px; height:50px;"/>
             <!--attendee name w-->
             <span class="rightNames"  style="">
                NAME 1
              </span>
          </div>
      <!--end-->
      
     </div>
      <div class="infoBoxFirstLine row " >
      
      <!--attendee profile image w-->
           <div class="leftImage" >
              <img src="" style="border-radius:150px; width:50px; height:50px;"/>
             <!--attendee name w-->
             <span class="rightNames"  style="">
                NAME 1
              </span>
          </div>
      <!--end-->
      
     </div>
     </div>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need 'ul' to be scrollable. And each '&User Name' only need one blue info box. Also the blue box should appear on the left and outside of the 'ul' area.

Comment: so ul scrollable should be accordingly y axis or x axis because if the record getting increases means number of <li></li> is getting increases so height is increasing accordingly x-axis

or once you hover your mouse on <a tag and box appear on left so there should be y-axis scrollable and scroll to left to see the hover box